# Moving points closer to polyline using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-table, arcgis-10.6, xy

I have a lot of points I need to move that are on the edge of the parcels closer to the centerline(road), not directly on top but about 5 feet away from the centerline.

I know i can edit and move the points manually but is there a way to automate the process using ModelBuilder?

[image]

Comment: Do you have advance license level?

Comment: yes i do have advance license level

Answer (score 4):

You'll need a Standard or higher license for this method. Create a buffer feature class from your centerlines with a 5 foot buffer distance. Then use the [Snap](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/snap.htm) tool. Your points are your input features. Your centerline buffers are your snap features. Use `Edge` as your type.

Answer (score 2):

Slight variation of 2 other solutions. Use Near tool (location) on your points and buffer. Calculate Shape field using calculator (Python):

```
arcpy.Point( !NEAR_X!, !NEAR_Y!)
```

Note: this will modify original shapes, so create a copy first. Difference with Snap tool - you don't need to guess distance, and generate near table looks like unnecessary complication.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use "generate near table" and then recalculate the geometry to move them.

***test this on a copy of your data as I'm typing this process from memory right now***

With Generate Near Table:
"input feature" is your points.
"Near feature" is a 5 foot buffer of your lines (alternatively you could use copy parallel to create new lines that are 5 feet on either side of the street centerlines and use those here)

check on the boxes for "location" and "Find only closest"

the output is a table of:

```
Input Point ObjectIDs (IN_FID)
Near line Object ID (NEAR_FID)
How far away that line is (NEAR_DIST) 
The current X and Y of your points (FROM_X and FROM_Y)
The nearest coordinate on the lines you want to move to (NEAR_X and NEAR_Y)
```

Join this table to your points and then you can move them by recalculating the (SHAPE*) field in your points table with this in the field calculator:

specify the parser as Python
click the box for "show Codebook"
put this in the Pre-Logic box:

```
def movePoint(shape, xCoord, yCoord):
  point = shape.getPart(0)
  point.X = xCoord
  point.Y = yCoord
  return point
```

then in the box below that, enter

mypoints.SHAPE =

```
movePoint( !SHAPE!, !neartable.NEAR_X! , !neartable.NEAR_Y! )
```

refresh the view and teh points should hopefully have moved to the new XY positions